# Python matplotlib not plotting correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a simple 2D figure, but the result is totaly incorrect. With `plot()` looks like X is assuming two different values, and with `scatter()`, Y and X are not "alligned".

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x = ['1/22/20', '1/23/20', '1/24/20', '1/25/20', '1/26/20', '1/27/20', '1/28/20', '1/29/20', '1/30/20', '1/31/20', '2/1/20', '2/2/20', '2/3/20', '2/4/20', '2/5/20', '2/6/20', '2/7/20', '2/8/20', '2/9/20', '2/10/20', '2/11/20', '2/12/20', '2/13/20', '2/14/20', '2/15/20', '2/16/20', '2/17/20', '2/18/20', '2/19/20', '2/20/20', '2/21/20', '2/22/20', '2/23/20', '2/24/20', '2/25/20', '2/26/20', '2/27/20', '2/28/20', '2/29/20', '3/1/20', '3/2/20', '3/3/20', '3/4/20', '3/5/20', '3/6/20', '3/7/20', '3/8/20', '3/9/20', '3/10/20', '3/11/20', '3/12/20', '3/13/20', '3/14/20', '3/15/20', '3/16/20', '3/17/20', '3/18/20', '3/19/20', '3/20/20', '3/21/20', '3/22/20', '3/23/20', '3/24/20', '3/25/20', '3/26/20', '3/27/20', '3/28/20', '3/29/20', '3/30/20', '3/31/20', '4/1/20', '4/2/20', '4/3/20', '4/4/20', '4/5/20', '4/6/20', '4/7/20', '4/8/20']


y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 13, 13, 20, 25, 31, 38, 52, 151, 151, 162, 200, 321, 372, 621, 793, 1021, 1546, 1924, 2247, 2554, 2985, 3417, 3904, 4256, 4579, 5717, 6836, 8044, 9056, 10360, 11130, 12161, 14034, 16170]


plt.plot(x,y)

plt.savefig("result.png", dpi=300)
```

[scatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsdZp.png)
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKMtc.png)
[image: expected result]

Comment: I don't think there should be any problem while using `scatter`. I have tried your code and results were as expected.

Comment: what i the version of the matplotlib?

Comment: I get a monotonically increasing "function" when I execute the code you provide. Not sure how you are getting your results. I would try to pinpoint what are the x,y values that are being incorrectly plotted. It's possible there is some date format issue.

Comment: how your expected plot looks like

Comment: I'm using matplotlib 2.2.5, and the result is supposed to look like an exponential function, but after 3/10/20, there's an "underline", and looks like Y is assuming two values for the same X.

Comment: I've added a third picture showing the expected result. The part inside the rectangle should not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 x = ['1/22/20', '1/23/20', '1/24/20', '1/25/20', '1/26/20', '1/27/20', '1/28/20', '1/29/20', '1/30/20', '1/31/20', '2/1/20', '2/2/20', '2/3/20', '2/4/20', '2/5/20', '2/6/20', '2/7/20', '2/8/20', '2/9/20', '2/10/20', '2/11/20', '2/12/20', '2/13/20', '2/14/20', '2/15/20', '2/16/20', '2/17/20', '2/18/20', '2/19/20', '2/20/20', '2/21/20', '2/22/20', '2/23/20', '2/24/20', '2/25/20', '2/26/20', '2/27/20', '2/28/20', '2/29/20', '3/1/20', '3/2/20', '3/3/20', '3/4/20', '3/5/20', '3/6/20', '3/7/20', '3/8/20', '3/9/20', '3/10/20', '3/11/20', '3/12/20', '3/13/20', '3/14/20', '3/15/20', '3/16/20', '3/17/20', '3/18/20', '3/19/20', '3/20/20', '3/21/20', '3/22/20', '3/23/20', '3/24/20', '3/25/20', '3/26/20', '3/27/20', '3/28/20', '3/29/20', '3/30/20', '3/31/20', '4/1/20', '4/2/20', '4/3/20', '4/4/20', '4/5/20', '4/6/20', '4/7/20', '4/8/20']
 y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 13, 13, 20, 25, 31, 38, 52, 151, 151, 162, 200, 321, 372, 621, 793, 1021, 1546, 1924, 2247, 2554, 2985, 3417, 3904, 4256, 4579, 5717, 6836, 8044, 9056, 10360, 11130, 12161, 14034, 16170]
 plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))`
 plt.xticks(rotation=90)
 plt.plot(x,y)
 plt.savefig("result.png", dpi=300)
 plt.show()
```

[Python Data Science Handbook by Jake VanderPlas](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.00-introduction-to-matplotlib.html) is a great source to learn plotting with matplotlib.

Comment: Didn't work either. After 3/10/20, Y is assuming two different values, as if the results were underlined after this specific date.

Comment: I have tried the code in Jupyter and it worked fine.